# Set the default value to choice column with visual studio(Custom Site Column)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, site-column

I have to set the default value to choice column which is custom column as-

```
 <Field ID="{76880880-e435-4367-84e9-04840e60aa52}" Name="testChoice" DisplayName="Test Choice" StaticName="Test Choice" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="SMC"><Default>Yes</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Yes</CHOICE> <CHOICE>No</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Any error you are getting. It seems you field definition is valid.

Comment: No, I don't have any error.
But I need this should be selected to "Yes" while adding the new item.

Comment: `Yes` should be selected according to your code. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but not yet getting me as I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Fields.AddFieldAsXml` as the following

```
  string CustomField = string.Concat("<Field Type='Choice' DisplayName='",
        columnName, "' Name='", columnName, "' ",
        "Format='Dropdown' Required='TRUE' Indexed='TRUE'><CHOICES>",
        "<CHOICE>Qassas</CHOICE><CHOICE>Item0</CHOICE>",
        "<CHOICE>Item2</CHOICE><CHOICE>Item1</CHOICE>",
        "<CHOICE>Item3</CHOICE><CHOICE>Item4</CHOICE>",
        "</CHOICES><Default>Qassas</Default>",
        "<Description>any thing.",
        "</Description></Field>");

        list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(CustomField , true,
            SPAddFieldOptions.AddFieldToDefaultView);
        list.Update();
```

Comment: What changes need to do in my tag-
 <Field ID="{76880880-e435-4367-84e9-04840e60aa52}" Name="testChoice" DisplayName="Test Choice" StaticName="Test Choice" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="SMC"><Default>Yes</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Yes</CHOICE> <CHOICE>No</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>

Comment: I am sorry I answered this based on your quest before update , regarding your update  your field tag structure looks good, so what's the issue

Comment: If not set as default , Should you try to deactivate the feature and restart IIS then activate it again

Comment: Yes, I have deactivated and again activated that feature.
Also I have removed content type from the list and again assigned still it's not working.

Comment: try to set <Default>Yes</Default> after the choices

Comment: At the above code in your quest it's before choices !

Comment: Initially, I have set after the choices. After searching on google it's above the choices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44673/discussion-between-ram-and-m-qassas).